# Moving Rails App to PostgreSQL - Integer Out of Range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, postgresql

I've been battling this for a few days now and I've stopped making any progress.

I'm starting to run PostgreSQL in development for my Rails 4/Ruby 2.0 application. A big part of this is migrating my data from Sqlite to PostgreSQL. I have a very data heavy application.

I'm following the instructions in the Railscast:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql

I have PostgreSQL up and running correctly.

I did run into a few problems migrating the data and found this piece on Github:
https://github.com/ricardochimal/taps/issues/128

I followed the instructions provided by hak8or which had me creating a separate streamlined app called "tmp" to migrate the data. All seemed to be moving well. The database schema was converted and tables started being copied over.

Then I received this error:

```
postgres.rb:175:in `exec': PG::NumericValueOutOfRange: ERROR:  integer out of range (Sequel::DatabaseError)
```

I did some looking at my data and realized I needed to change one column to a bigint. So I created and ran a migration and restarted the data migration. Sadly, I still have the same error.

The conversion seems to be going in the order the tables were created. I've checked the next table which should be converted and there are only two integer fields. One is the ID and the other is the ID for a relationship and that one is still empty.

Does anyone have any ideas? I'm completely stumped.

Comment: Is the column in question an `integer` or `bigint`? What is the value that is causing problems?

Comment: The first time I saw this error I changed the offending column to bigint and was able to get past that table. Now I'm getting the same error and the data doesn't have any values remotely close to the maximum value for an integer of 2147483647.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a bit of investigation I found that the column that I changed to a "bigint" was somehow being converted back to a regular integer column when I tried to migrate the data.

The easiest way I found to fix this was to create a new column of the type "bigint" copy the information from the Integer column into the "bigint" column and then delete the old Integer column.

Answer (score -1):

In Ruby on Rails for bigint (Postgre) use **decimal** instead **integer**.
Like:

```
  def change
    create_table :profiles do |t|
      t.decimal :mybigfieldnumber
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

Instead of:

```
  def change
    create_table :profiles do |t|
      t.integer :mybigfieldnumber   
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```